# run bunch of commands and wait

Tags: shell-script

I want to run bunch of commands simultaneously and when all of them finished, run another bunch of commands.some thing like this
command1 & command2
echo "command 1 and 2 finished"
command 3 & command 4

Comment: Look into using the wait command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
command1 &
command2 &

wait
echo 'command1 and command2 have finished'

command3 &
command4 &

wait
echo 'command3 and command4 have finished'
```

The call to `wait` will pause the script until all backgrounded tasks have finished executing.

Alternatively (just "for your information"), depending on whether you want command 1 and 2 to run concurrently or not (equivalently for command 3 and 4):

```
( command1; command2 ) &
echo 'command1 and command2 are running'
wait
echo 'command1 and command2 have finished'
```

In the above case, `command1` and `command2` will run in the background, but not concurrently with each other.

---

Doing

```
command1 & command2
wait
```

is equivalent to

```
command1 &
command2
wait
```

... which will work, but `command2` will not be running in the background and `wait` will not be called until `command2` has finished executing.

Comment: Problem is that I have some other tasks running already in the background. Lets call them `&1` and `&2`. Is there a version of this where I can capture the task ids of `command1` and `command2`, then do a `wait &3 &4`? Ta.

Comment: @Leo The process ID (PID) of the most recently started background task is available in `$!`. You could save these in an array (`pids+=( "$!" )` after starting a job) and then wait for them (`wait "${pids[@]}"`).  That's assuming you have a shell that supports arrays.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll try. In the meantime maybe you could add the answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554602/wait-for-processes-started-in-a-for-loop-but-not-others-started-earlier

Answer (score 1):

The actual answer of my question was something like this, special thanks from @raman-sailopal

```
command1 & command2
wait
echo "command 1 and 2 has finished"
command3 & command4
```

Comment: That will work, but thu `wait` will only wait for `command1` as `command2` is not run as a background task.  The same goes for `command4`.

Answer (score 0):

```
command1 & command2; echo "command1 & 2 complete" && command3 & command4; echo "command3 & 4 complete"
```

`&` runs commands simultaneously

`;` emulates a new line - i.e. will be run after completion

`&&` runs once the previous job has finished, provided the previous job was successful (i.e. didn't return any exit code but 0)

Comment: This doesn’t work: `command1` will run in the background, the first `echo` will run as soon as `command2` completes, regardless of whether `command1` has finished. Likewise for `command3`.