# `wait` for processes started in a for loop, but not others started earlier

Tags: bash, background-process, wait

Suppose I have several running background tasks, but now I want to run two more background tasks, but wait only for the last two. For example:

```bsh
# long running commands
sleep 60 &
sleep 60 &

# now wait only for these two:
sleep 5 & sleep 5 & wait; echo waited only for the 5s sleeps.
```

The result of the command above is that the echo command waits 60s.

I know I can [pass a pid or jobid to wait](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash). But since I am starting the processes in a `for` loop, I can't easily get the PIDs.

I tried this, but no luck:

```bsh
{ sleep 3 & sleep 5 & } wait; echo did not wait :

sleep 10 & { sleep 3 ; sleep 3 ; }& wait %2; echo only wait 3s
```

P.S.: This question is an extension of [this simpler question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/418796/120821).

Answer (score 1):

You could start a subshell:

```
{ sleep 20 && echo second output ; }
( sleep 2 & wait && echo first output )
```

The `wait` command in the subshell will only be valid there.

Comment: Won't this simply block until the `sleep 20` completes?

Comment: How about this variation: `sleep 4 & ( sleep 2 & wait && echo inner process ) & wait && echo outer_process`

Comment: No it wont, note that the first is a grouping, where the second is a subshell.

Answer (score 0):

Based on guidance from @Kusalananda in the simpler question I came up with this example. Maybe not the simplest...

All the code below is in an interactive shell. I just broke it into parts for the answer because it would otherwise be hard to read.

Beware that in `bash` version 4.1 and older, the `!` in the `""`, triggers history substitution in an interactive shell (this was fixed in release 4.2). That is what I was getting tricked by. If you really want to quote `$!` you can use `"$! "` and the trailing space will prevent history substitution from kicking in.

```bsh
unset to_wait; 

date; 
sleep 3 & 

for i in 1 2 3; do 
    sleep 1 &
    # Don't put the ! in "" or you'll get an `event`. 
    to_wait+=( $! ); 
done; 
wait "${to_wait[@]}"; 

date; 
echo waited 1s for inner processes; 

# wait for the rest of the processes (just for illustration)
wait; 

date; 
echo waited 3s for outer process;
```

Comment: The issue with history events will not occur in a non-interactive script like this. `$!` should definitely be quoted.

Comment: Yes, the actual case is an interactive shell. I've tried escaping the ! unsuccessfully. Do you have a suggestion? And, BTW, in this special case where the variable is numeric, why is quoting absolutely necessary?

Comment: I wonder what you did to have `bash` see `$!` as a history event. I really can't reproduce that, not even in an interactive shell (quoted and unquoted). What `bash` version are you using? macOS with `bash` 3.2.57? That bug was fixed in later `bash` versions. In the meanwhile, you _could_ use `"$! "` instead (with a space).  You'd want to quote it, especially in an interactive shell, just in case `$IFS` happens to contain digits (for whatever reason).

Comment: Bash 4.1.2 (RHEL 6). I'll update the answer to make it clear that the commands above are happening in an interactive shell. The extra space, i.e., `"$! "` should work, although I wonder which is more obscure: adding a space after a variable to avoid history expansion; or protecting against an `$IFS` containing a digit.

Comment: I tend to opt for the defensive option when I give away code on this site. I wouldn't want code from here end up in production system with obvious (or not so obvious) flaws in it just because someone did not understand the commands they were copying and pasting.  There was a SE blog post related to that recently: https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/26/copying-code-from-stack-overflow-you-might-be-spreading-security-vulnerabilities/

Comment: You mean people cut-and-paste without understanding the answers? I'm shocked and appalled!

Comment: Yeah, strange, isn't it?